# ReadAsAsync got null values from Json data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I have a class

```
public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SqlXml Range { get; set; } // System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml
}
```

And the following code is used to read the data from web api.

```
    List<C> cs = null;
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        cs = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<C>>(); // cs[..].Range is null
    }
```

The following is some sample Json file returned from the Web API.

```
[{"id":0,"range":{"isNull":false,"value":"<Range>....</Range>"}},
 {"id":1,"range":{"isNull":false,"value":"<Range>...</Range>"}},
 {"id":2,"range":{"isNull":false,"value":"<Range>....</Range>"}}]
```

However, the variable `cs` got the following values. The `Id` values are correct. But all the `Range`s got null values?

```
0, null
1, null
2, null
```

The debugger shows `cs[...].Range.IsNull` is `true`.

Comment: Did you get the previous issue sorted out?

Comment: Can you show definition of `SqlXml` class. maybe json.net is unable to desrialize that object, but will need to see what it looks like.

Comment: SqlXml is in `System.Data.SqlTypes`. I didn't define it.

Comment: Ok I'll go take a look at it.

Comment: those properties are read only.

Comment: Which properties are read-only? I didn't modify the property `IsNull` but just check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml(v=vs.110).aspx) are read only. When the deserializer tries to create objects of that type it will fail while trying to set the properties.

Create you own class to hold the desired values

```
public class Range {
    public bool IsNull { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class C {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Range Range { get; set; }
}
```

This should now allow the `Range` values to be properly populated